# Sailsjs policies not taking effect

Tags: sails.js

I'm having trouble with policies/routes in Sails 0.9.16.  Whatever I do, the /user path remains unprotected. Clearly I am doing something incorrectly.

I have the following routes:

```
'/': {
    view: 'home/index'
},

'get /login': {
view: 'login'
},

'post /login': {
  controller: 'UserController',
  action: 'login'
},
```

And the following policies:

```
module.exports.policies = {
   '*'    : false,
   user   : {
   '*': 'isAuthenticated'
   },
   login  : {
   '*' :true 
   },
}
```

From the routes and policies you can see that I want to have /login route unprotected, and the /user/* path protected.  My isAuthenticated.js is the stock created with a new sails project.

The UserController correctly matches the password and sets req.session.authenticated = true.

I'm lost as to how to sort this out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, Sails' policies are being applied per controller/action, not per route. Also, check [here](http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/policies) for the proper structure. So, your `config/policies.js` should become something like:

```
module.exports.policies = {
  UserController: {
    '*': 'isAuthenticated',
    login: true
  }
}
```

Comment: That's right, I was wondering this for so many hours! I think is a little misleading the fact that by default, sails comes with the "/": { view: "homepage" } default route for the / (so no policy will ever apply to /).

Comment: @DiegoPamio True story. On the other hand, view-based routing is supposed to handle mostly static content, like about-disclaimer-terms kind of pages, which is usually unprotected.

Comment: So is it possible to block all incoming requests (for testing purpose)? It doesn't work even if I set '*' to false. If I want to achieve this, should I wrap the homepage in a controller rather than map it to a static file in routes?

Comment: @IsilmëO. Docs are not clear enough at this point, but [here](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/d253a409a85f72878dedaaa30397ad3c8d14d049/reference/Routes/Routes.md#notes) it's implicitly said that view routes are not being affected by the policies. So, yes, you would have to change the default route to pass through a controller instead.

Comment: @bredikhin Seems I've got to work this way. Just a little confused why they put '*': true in the default policy document even though it doesn't work actually. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As of Sails 0.11 policies can be applied to [custom routes](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/routes/custom-routes#?policy-target-syntax):

```
'/foo': {policy: 'myPolicy'}
```

Blueprint route with policy:

```
'/foo': [{policy: 'myPolicy'}, {blueprint: 'find', model: 'user'}]
```

View route with policy:

```
'/foo': [{policy: 'myPolicy'}, {view: 'foobar'}]
```